# PanGesture event interfering with scrubber scrubbing event

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, uislider, uipangesturerecognizer

I am implementing a scrubber for a video player and I've encountered an problem. **The parent view of the video player(also the parent view of my scrubber) has a panGesture.** When the users slide the scrubber bottom-right by a little, it will slide the scrubber by a little bit, and call the IBAction function `ScrubberMovementBegins`, but I think because of the panGesture interference, it won't call the IBAction func `ScrubberMovementEnds` , which makes my scrubber seem buggy.

**Anyone has encountered this or has a good solution to prevent this from happening?**

Comment: Could you provide a small example that is minimal and reproduces the error you are describing? It is a bit tough to be able to help without being able to debug or see the error directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straight forward solution is to ignore the panGesture if it is coming from UISlide.

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing issues in `IBOutlet` or `IBAction` **func()** then try to use `@objc` **func()** and implement selector to the `panGesture` or `control`.

```
@objc func isMoving(){

   //Your Code

}
```